# Find the longest path in graph

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I am trying to find the longest path in a graph but I'm having trouble when it comes to returning the longest path. I have the recursion figured out and can follow the outputs but I can't get the right output. The program currently returns several paths.

The expected output is when starting from Las Vegas: [Las Vegas, Salt Lake City, Denver, Helena, Winnipeg, Duluth]

My depth first search method:

```
public void dfs(City before, ArrayList<String> listOfCities){

    System.out.println(before +"-->"+ before.getAdjCities());

    List<City> neighbours = before.getAdjCities();
    before.setVisited(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.size(); i++) {

        City n = neighbours.get(i);
        if(!n.visited){
            listOfCities.add(n.getCityName());
            System.out.println(i+ " Test: " + listOfCities.toString());

            dfs(n, listOfCities);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is the graph:

[image]

Comment: Use Neo4j and ask it to match the longest path: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/achieving-longestpath-using-cypher/

Comment: I am stuck at similar problem, can you share this corrected code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ListOfCities is static across all branches of your search, which is why it ends up with all the cities. The recursive step at each city should compare the result of the DFS from each neighbor to build the result.

Comment: How would the comparison work?/Where would it go? I've tried moving things around but can't get anything working

Comment: Change the return type of dfs to `List<City>` and return the current city at the head of the longest result.

Comment: How do I know which one is longer?

Comment: Add a variable, initially holding an empty list - and for each iteration of the loop, and `if (dfsResult.size() > currentLongest.size()) currentLongest = dfsResult;`